# External HDD gets into read only mode over and over again

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, read-only

I have an extarnal HDD that put itself in read only mode on a regular base. For the record I know how to solve this problem via Diskpart. I even have created a script for it!

The problem is that it happens to often and I have no idea why. After searching for a long time, I couldn't found anything that is explaining this phenomenon. First I  thought it has something todo with plugging or unplugging but it happens randomly.

It is a WD 500 GB external HDD (WD Elements Desktop [WD5000E035](http://support.wdc.com/product/install.asp?groupid=301)) , connected via usb 2, and it is used to backup the Windows system partition. The  disk is a few years old. Could this be a kind of hardware failure? Lately it happens more often.

The HDD (MBR) has only one partition, no hidden partitions (so no WD utilities installed), no applications are running from the the disk, it is purely used for backups.

The script that I use (and it is working fine):

> SELECT VOLUME W
>
> ATTRIBUTES VOLUME CLEAR READONLY
>
> SELECT DISK 6
>
> ATTRIBUTES DISK CLEAR READONLY

I have also an other external HDD that doesn't has this problem

Anyone an idea what causes this problem.

Thanks,
Mumblic

Comment: can you post the diskpart script? and do you run any applications from that hdd? Personally I would move the data off the hdd and wipe it clean. Get rid of any WD utitities or hidden partitions on that hdd.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my post. Cleaning the disk (full format) did not solve the problem. It stay a mystery ;-)

Answer (score 0):

WD External HDDs are known for a hidden utility partition, that can not be removed from Windows easily without using a 3rd party application.

Best way is to use a Linux Live Cd (Gparted, Parted Magic or similiar) 
They can be found from here and more... http://www.livecdlist.com/

If you want to do it from Windows, you can try using HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool

Comment: Hi, Logman. Like mentioned before. There are NO hidden partitions. Just one single partition. I double checked for you with different tools. At the moment a complete chkdsk is running. Once completed I will do a last check with Gparted. I doubt I will see something different.

Comment: only an application can change readonly status, it is not hw... so something on the hdd or some application on your system is doing it.